# Ktor Client, how to specify body parameters

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor-client

I'm trying to send a POST request to the server, this post requires parameters "email" and "password".
but I don't know how to specify parameters, I read the documentation but I didn't understand.
this is my code:

```
val request=client.post<String> {
    url(BASE_URL+"login.php")
    body="email=$email,password=$password"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fwiw I use something like following here....though I would have thought specifying `url` like you do should also work.  What issue do you see?  The body might also be some json for example, or maybe a data class etc if you have serialization setup.

```
            response = client.post(url) {
                body = "some params/data etc"
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I used 'Uploading multipart/form-data' to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use serialization, but I solved my problem by using 'Uploading multipart/form-data'

```
val request=client.post(url) {
      body=MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
          append("email","data")
          append("password","data")
      })
}
```

see [Documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#multipart-form-data)